# Proper style/use of parenthesis

Tags: math-mode, text, parenthesis

I'm using 'mathpazo' for text and math. One thing I have noticed is that the style of the parentheses in text and math mode are not alike. What would you use?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}\linespread{1.05}
\begin{document}
Text mode: $($text$)$ or (text)

Math mode: $(x=30)$ or ($x=30$)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, but the same "problem" is still there if I remove 'mathabx'.

Comment: Perhaps you should give a try at the `newpx`  package, based on the `URW Palladio` clone of Palatino`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's really good to load `mathabx` along with `mathpazo`; however, the problem of parentheses appears anyway, due to the fact that the parentheses in the `upright` math symbol font are apparently taken from Computer Modern.

You can cure it by changing the parentheses in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}\linespread{1.05}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen} {operators}{`(}{largesymbols}{"00}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{operators}{`)}{largesymbols}{"01}


\begin{document}
Text mode: $($text$)$ or (text)

Math mode: $(x=30)$ or ($x=30$)

$(\big(\Big(\bigg(\Bigg($
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another solution is not using `mathpazo`, but NewPX, which I recommend.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\linespread{1.05}

\begin{document}
Text mode: $($text$)$ or (text)

Math mode: $(x=30)$ or ($x=30$)

$(\big(\Big(\bigg(\Bigg($
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have 'newpxtext' and 'newpxmath' installed on my PC. Tried using the guide here: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newpx. But it also require 'newtx­math', 'px­fonts', and 'TEXGyrePag­ella', and I can't get it to work!

Comment: @TobiasDK You apparently have a rather old TeX distribution.

Comment: MikTex 2.9, updated yesterday. Maybe I have damaged the FNDB and Formats system, when trying to install all the packages?!?

Comment: @TobiasDK NewPX is not at all *that* new. It's regularly updated, but it was already in TeX Live 2012. And, sorry, I know almost nothing about MiKTeX, because none of my machines can run it.

Comment: Got it to work now :-) Found the missing packages in "Package Manager".

Comment: No doubt the *packages* are more up to date, but MikTex 2.9 itself was released way back in 2010, and there is "no planned date" for the upcoming version 3.0. Refs: http://miktex.org/2.9/status http://miktex.org/3.0/status. FWIW I gave up waiting for some bugfixes to the *code* in Miktex 2.9 back in 2012, and moved to TexLive.

Comment: Does this solution apply for `[]`, ex: `$[x=30]$ or [$x=30$]` as well?

Comment: @alper I’m not sure what you’re referring to

Comment: Can I think think solution for all types of paranthesis like `[`?

Answer (score 3):

> One thing I have noticed is that the style of the parenthes[e]s in text and math mode are not alike. What would you use?

Regardless of the font families you may be employing, the prescriptive answer regarding the use of parentheses is straightforward:

- Use math-mode parentheses if, syntactically speaking, the material -- *including the parentheses* -- is math-y. E.g., `We now study the term $(a+b)(c+d)$ in further detail.` Here, the first opening parenthesis and the second closing parenthesis clearly belong to the formula. It would be very poor form to write `... the term ($a+b)(c+d$) in ...`
- Use text-mode parentheses if the parentheses themselves, syntactically speaking, are part of the text, even if some or all of the material they enclose is math-y. E.g., `The first case ($a<0$) is more difficult to handle than the second ($a\ge 0$).` In the preceding sentence, the parentheses are, syntactically speaking, *not* part of the math formulas.

Of course, if the text and math fonts are well-matched, the reader may not notice a difference in appearance of basic-size parentheses. Nevertheless, it's worth being careful about these distinctions. For instance, if you decide to re-publish your paper using a new set of text and math fonts, with text-mode and math-mode parentheses looking quite different, you'll be glad you don't have to over the document again just to fix which type of parentheses belong to text and math material.

Comment: @TobiasDK - Keep in mind that the prescriptive rule laid out above applies to other items -- e.g., commas -- as well: If the comma is part of the math expression, set it in math mode; otherwise, set it in text mode. Thus, write `Let $a_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$, be a non-negative number`: two commas in text mode, and two commas in math mode.

Comment: What do you mean by `math-y` ? Would it be possible for you to add simple examples into two items you pointed?

Comment: @alper - I was using "math-y" as an informal adjectival form of the noun "math" -- or, if you prefer, "maths". I've updated my answer to address your request.